# Clickonce Https: An error occurred trying to download https://

Tags: ssl, clickonce

I have big problem when I am trying to deploy my app over clickonce.

I have this error:
An error occurred trying to download `https://<myappaddress>`

I think there is problem with SSL certificate, becose is signed for diferent domain.
SSL certificate is signed for pipni.cz and i have url https://someserve.com/cliconce

Is there any solution?

Thank a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more likely that ClickOnce doesn't support https. Have you tried deploying and installing with just http?

Comment: Clickonce supports https. But my ssl certificate is not valid. is signed for different domain name - standard free hosting issue. So I need to buy my own ssl cert.